# How to assign('=') collection of objects to model's assiciation with sql update delayed to save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

When parent is not saved assigning collection of objects(ActiveRecord_Relation, or might be ids for association_singular_ids=) to its has_many association does not produce SQL update. On the other hand if parent is saved already - such operation produces immediate SQL update. How to delay this query to be more like in the first instance?

Update 1.

Parent has_many :children

```
child = Child.create
child_2 = Child.create
parent = Parent.new
parent.children = Child.all
-> no SQL update is executed

child = Child.create
child_2 = Child.create
parent = Parent.create
parent.children = Child.all
-> runs SQL update for children's parent_id
```

Comment: Can you try to explain this a bit better or add a code example? Please respond by editing the question - not commenting.

Comment: Updates with some code. Here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html , is documentation on few methods I have tried(collection<<(object, …), collection=objects, collection_singular_ids=ids)

Comment: Why do you need to save the children explicitly before the parent? Normally you would do `parent = Parent.create; parent.children.create` and it will create a single INSERT query for the child.

Comment: My reallife usecase is in an UPDATE request for parent. So the children and the parent are already in database. Then I would like to reassign children if there is a change then run some complex validation and only if that passes - save parent and association to database.